# View is compressing from left and right edge on modal presentation

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI form view is behaving strange when a presentation was started.
Edge layout's for left and right is breaking

Any idea to avoid this problem ?

```
struct FormActionTest: View {
@State var isShow : Bool = false
var body: some View {
    Form{
        HStack{
                Text("TEST")
                Spacer()
                Text("TEST")
            }
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.isShow.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Alert")
            }
        }
    }.actionSheet(isPresented: $isShow, content: {
        ActionSheet(title: Text("TEST"))
    })
}
```

Using Xcode Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44) tried in simulator and real devices.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common visual bug with `List` and `Form`, still present in Xcode 11.2. Just [report it](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) and wait for a fix, unfortunately.

Comment: I reported it. Thank you.